# pplx::task with daemon not executed

Tags: c++, linux, daemon, casablanca

I have a problem with pplx::task from cpprest (casablanca). After forking my process to create a daemon, the tasks are not executed and wait forever.

```
auto task = pplx::create_task([] {
std::cout << "Hi I'm a task " << std::endl;
});
task.wait();

// Create daemon process (not included for simplicity)

auto notWorkingTask = pplx::create_task([] {
    std::cout << "Hi I'm a task in daemon" << std::endl;
});
notWorkingTask.wait();
```

Any idea how to archieve that ? I suppose there is a boost::asio::io_service on background and need to notify it with :

```
boost::asio::io_service::notify_fork(boost::asio::prepare_fork);
```

Sysout (this is simulated one, we use syslog because daemon has no access to sysout)

```
Hi I'm a task
```

Edit : There are a feature request [here](https://casablanca.codeplex.com/workitem/68) 
Somebody know a workaround ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we have patched casablanca, there is a working example for Android  :

```
/include/pplx/threadpool.h
```